# How can I pin osd-lyrics to the Desktop?

Tags: 10.10, gnome, compiz

I have certain applications pinned to my desktop. such as

- Rainlendar (1), which offers this option in the settings window
- conky (2), with "own_window_type normal" in my ~/.conkyrc
- Rhythmbox's Desktop Cover Art plugin (3), a python plugin sticked to the desktop.

They all hide nicely below all other Windows. I set Compiz to not minimize them on "show desktop" command using "window rules".

I also use [osd-lyrics](http://code.google.com/p/osd-lyrics) to display music lyrics. It's default behaviour is to stick always on top, which is irritating sometimes and, in my case, looks rather fugly. (4)
See screenshot:

[image]

Now how can I tell Compiz to pin the osd-lyrics bar to the desktop below all other windows and not minimize it? I tried all sorts of window rules and exceptions, e.g. using "class=osd-lyrics", "title=osd-lyrics" but the OSD doesn't seem to match any of these.

Any ideas?

**Running:** Ubuntu 10.10 Maverick Meerkat, Compiz 0.8.6, osd-lyrics 0.3 from

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am closing it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyways or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reasons why you want it open. Regards